# R pheatmap: use logarithmic scaling in the legend

Tags: r, pheatmap

I have a matrix

```
library(pheatmap)
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.001), ncol=20)
pheatmap(mat)
```

and there is one value that is much higher than the rest. Therefore, I would like to use a logarithmic scaling for the legend bar (1, 10, 100, 1000, ...).

Is there a possibility to do that with the `pheatmap` package?

EDIT: I don't want to make `log(mat)`, I only want the color scaling bar be scaled logarithmic (1, 10, 100, 1000, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add logarithmic `legend_breaks` and show a label for the maximum.

```
pheatmap::pheatmap(mat, legend_breaks=c(10^(0:ceiling(log10(max(mat)))), 
                                        round(max(mat), 2)))
```

***Yielding***

[image: plot]

Comment: This doesn't space the breakpoints on the legend in a logarithmic fashion. Either this isn't a solution or I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @flies It only considers values in the data and also shows the maximum which is below what the next logarithmic breakpoint, 10K, would be. That's probably what is confusing you.

Comment: if you instead use `rexp(400...)` you get `legend_breaks==c(1,10,100, 1000, 10k, 6331.28)`, and you'll see that the 10 sits right on top of the 100 instead of having equal distance between 10, 100, and 1000.